# Portable USB-C Monitor locks up 16" Macbook Pro 2019

Tags: macbook-pro, display, performance

I just bought a small portable 1080p 14" USB-C Monitor to use with my 2019 16" Macbook Pro: https://www.amazon.de/ARZOPA-Tragbarer-1920x1080-Bildschirm-Telefon-Silber/dp/B09Q2WYRKD

For some reason, when it's plugged in, the monitor powers up, then immediately says 'No signal', then my Macbook Pro locks up where the mouse freezes, screen goes dark, then appears back much darker and is just frozen.

As soon as I unplug the monitor, the laptop is perfectly usable again immediately.

I recorded console logs and noticed a few errors that seem relevant:

```
default 22:03:10.708481+0200    WindowServer    [WARN] - IOFBSetDisplayModeAndDepth: Failed to obtain mode info from IOFBGetDisplayModeInformation()
default 22:03:10.708554+0200    kernel  [3:0:0] [FB:0] AmdRadeonFramebuffer::getPixelInformation() !!! Invalid display mode: 0xc0003068.
```

Plugging it into an M1 Macbook Air works perfectly so it isn't a hardware/cable issue and both machines are running Monterey 12.3

Comment: Does this also happen if you shut the system down, attach the display, and then boot? What about shutting down, attaching display, and booting to Boot Picker (hold Option while pressing power button until icons appear)?

Comment: Install 12.3.1... that update is supposed to fix problems with external USBC monitors.

Comment: @MarcWilson this is the answer, you are correct, updating to 12.3.1 fixed it! Would you like to post this as the answer so it can be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Monterey 12.3.1 update.  From Apple:

> This update fixes the following issues:
>
> - USB-C or Thunderbolt external display does not turn on when connected to Mac mini (2018) as a second display

It seems to fix the problem on a variety of machines besides the Mini.